# SSRS cannot deploy

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, bids

I am an db admin on the server. I have granted the user with "SYSTEM user" on site setting, "Content Manager" on the Home folder, and also "Content Manager" on the her folder XXX.

However, she cannot deploys her report on BIDS and get this error instead:

> The permissions granted to user 'WMSERVICE\xxx' are insufficient for performing this operation

I have gone through many site and most of the suggestion is to run it back as Administrator, or give her a SYSTEM Administrator privilege for the SSRS (this is the last resort that I should consider).

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need system-level permissions to deploy objects to SSRS. Please post a screenshot of the report project properties from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things on SSRS:

1. SSRS has two permissions, roles and user levels.  Giving someone a permssion role of admin to SSRS is not like giving them admin under Active Directory.  Just to SSRS.  You could always try that and see if that is the issue.
2. Is the user publishing to multiple locations with the:

Data Source(s)

Data Set(s)

Reports

Or are they self contained in the report itself?

They can tell by going into a Report Project and hitting properties and looking at their screen settings.  If they are using 'Shared Data Sources' or 'Shared Data Sets' that adds more levels of complexity to the security issues as you have to deal with their deployment as well.  If one of those report folders is different they may be getting denied.  For a sub part of the total in which their deployment would tell them which object was failing and were at.  Many times I have seen people NOT turn off the default for Data Sources which is root/Data Sources.  SSRS can deploy a project, data source, data set, or report and it's dependencies.  When in doubt give full access and verify it works, then remove access immiediately.  Then trouble shoot deployments.  It is probably a folder not being given rights to and then deployment is going for that folder first would be my guess.